# How to use parameters for this JS function?

Tags: javascript, function, html5-canvas

I have the following function which prints out a few squares in the shape of a pixel letter. Right now you'll notice I've only got letters a and b in there. Eventually I'll add all the characters but first I need to know how to write this function so that I can pass a parameter to it, and it will print out the shapes to look like the letter you passed into the function as the parameter. Here is the function now:

```
function make_letter() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
    var w = parseInt(getComputedStyle(c).width);
    var h = parseInt(getComputedStyle(c).height);
    var full = Math.floor(h / 16);
    var unit = full - 0.75;
    var inv = {
        a: [[0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 0], [3, 4], [4, 0], [4, 4]],
        b: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 4], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3,4], [4,0], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3]]
    };
    for (i = 0; i <= inv.b.length; i++) {
        var x = inv.b[i][1] * full;
        var y = inv.b[i][0] * full;
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(x, y, unit, unit); 
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

I'd like to call the function with `make_letter('a');` and have it print a letter that matches the letter that you pass, but at some points in the function I'm not sure how to incorporate the parameter variable correctly. Like in this line: `for (i = 0; i <= inv.b.length; i++) {` how do I tell it to use inv.param.length assuming 'param' is the name of the parameter variable passed into the function?

Here is a fiddle of the original function: http://jsfiddle.net/po74m2ut/

Comment: `inv[param].length` See http://jsfiddle.net/po74m2ut/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function make_letter(letter) {
    ...
    for (i = 0; i <= inv[letter].length; i++) {
        var x = inv[letter][i][1] * full;
        var y = inv[letter][i][0] * full;
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(x, y, unit, unit); 
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

In my last answer, I almost explained this case - guess I should have! This is the time when you actually want to use the `object[property]` form of reference rather than `object.property`...when the actual name of the property is stored in a variable.

Another way of writing that loop would be:

```
inv[letter].forEach(function(coord) {
   context.beginPath();
   context.rect(coord[1] * full, coord[0] * full, unit, unit); 
   context.fillStyle = 'black';
   context.fill();
});
```

Comment: I'll pick this as the answer as soon as the timer is up.

Comment: No problem! Edited to add another way of doing that loop. Nothing wrong with using a `for` loop to generate indexes to traverse an array, but `Array.forEach()` teaches you to start thinking in functional terms, which can be useful later with things like `Array.map()` and `Array.reduce()`.

Comment: There was another answer which looks like it's been deleted, but it mentioned that the `context.fillStyle()` and `context.fill()` calls could be taken out of the loop and executed once afterward. Sounded like a good idea.